# load testing of "cookieless Session" asp.net

Tags: asp.net, testing, session, load, cookieless

I have been trying using MS VSTS 2008, no luck so far..

After the redirection from server to accomodate the sessionID in URL, the test fails during the first time recording.

I am open to looking at other tools which are not very expensive.

Does anyone have any experience using any tool for testing cookieless sessionID website?